# Interpretation and use of the logarithmic scale for high school students

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, physics, applications

Often when we discuss on the logarithms in high school we also talk about a scale called logarithmic.

[image]

In the he logarithmic scale: the distance from $1$ to $2$ is the same as the distance from $2$ to $4$, or from $4$ to $8$ as the image below.

There are many applications of the logarithmic scale: Weber-Fecner's law, sound intensity perceived by our hear hearings, the brightness of a star, etc.. What is the optimal solution or explanation for understanding how to make students build a logarithmic scale and its utility?

Comment: This is probably more suitable for math educators stack exchange

Comment: What do you mean by "how to build a logarithmic scale "? Is this a mathematical problem? Sorry, If I have misunderstood it.

Comment: @enedil I'm interested because of the very good users who are members of this community also their point of view.

Comment: @user710290 Hi, I have edited with that now is more clear. Don't worry but I use the deepl translator :-( and many times it is not very clear my some questions.

Comment: This isn't really an answer so I'll leave it as a comment - but I think you could probably look at a lot of different functions as sort of "stretching the number line" in a sense by looking at what happens to the distances between numbers before and after applying the function $f$. In this context, you are looking at functions more as (not necessarily linear) transformations of the number line

Comment: @Riemann'sPointyNose I'd like you to put an answer with some examples in mathjax so I can remember some passages.

Comment: The Wikipedia article [Slide rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slide_rule) may be helpful. Up to a few decades ago they were used in high schools.

Comment: @Somos I have seen and thank you for your support. Unfortunately, today's students are more and more vulnerable, in knowledge, in study and they want everything and immediately. I fight ignorance but often a teacher is asked to explain a lesson in five minutes. This is possible if the students remember the basic elements of mathematics: I always repeat that ignorance reigns sovereign.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I remember correctly, this video does a really good job at this sort of thing: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CfW845LNObM .

What you have shown above is just a different way of looking at what exactly a function does. For example, let's say we had

$${f(x) = x + 1}$$

This just "moves the number line left 1 unit" - but it does not affect the distance between two numbers. The numbers $0$ and $1$ have a distance of $1$ between them, and ${f(0)}$ and ${f(1)}$ has a distance of ${f(1)-f(0)=2-1=1}$ between them also - the distances stay the same!

Another example is

$${f(x) = 2x}$$

In this case, the distances between numbers are affected. Take the same example of $0$ and $1$ - ${f(0) = 0, f(1) = 2}$, and so ${f(0)}$ and ${f(1)}$ have a distance of $2$ between them - it's double the distance! And you can show that ${\left|f(y) - f(x)\right|=2\left|y-x\right|}$. The distance between numbers *always* get's doubled under this "transformation". So this function $f$ is a transformation that does stretch the number line.

So the Logarithmic scale is just showing you how the distances between two numbers get changed under ${\log(x)}$ as a transformation. And because ${\log(x)}$ grows so slowly - we expect distances between numbers under the transformation to get closer and closer together - just as you see in the picture.

We have some special names for how distances get changed too. Lipschitz mappings are mappings such that

$${|f(y)-f(x)|\leq k|x-y|}$$

For some constant $k$, and Contraction mappings are Lipschitz mappings with ${0\leq k<1}$. In fact one of the (in my opinion) coolest theorems ever is the contraction mapping theorem - but this is getting quite complicated :)

Comment: Thank you very very much. You can see my last comment of the user @Somos.